# Function with one local parameter of default value

Tags: c++, c++11

I`m trying to find a method that compiles without error and does the fallowing thing :

```
template <class A>
void f(A a,A b=a){
//do something
}
```

But when I call this function like `f<int>(3)` the compiler tell me that local variable `a` may not appear in the context.
I suppose that this is because the compiler can not know if a value would be assign to formal parameter `a` so that it could initialize formal parameter `b` with the value of `a`.

Is there any equivalent way/mode that i can implement such a function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could provide an overload that calls the two-parameter version:

```
template <class A>
void f(A a, A b){
  //do something
}

template <class A>
void f(A a){
  f(a, a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I suppose I can do the same with a constructor also no ?

Comment: Yes, that should work in the same way as this example.

Comment: Tnx...this save me a lot of time.... If I could not find a solution to this i must write all the code again. :D